# Time delay between the cycles

Tags: ros, rostime, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

I have below snippet of the code.

```
 ros::Rate rate(50);
 while (ros::ok())
 {
       ros_time = ros::Time::now();
       //Do some operations
       //Publish messages
       rate.sleep();
       ros.SpinOnce();
  }
```

I want to know the time gap/delay between each publish of messages. Could you please let me know if there a way to fetch the time delay ?

Thank you,
KK

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296077/time-delay-between-the-cycles/) by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 262 on 2018-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two things, firstly yes you can measure durations using the ros::Time module very easily. Secondly the delay between each iteration of this loop should be 0.02 seconds assuming that the code within the loop doesn't take longer than that to execute. That's what the ros::Rate::sleep method does, it waits until the requested time has elapsed since the last time it was called.

Are you trying to measure the time between subsequent calls to ros::Time::now() at the top of the loop? If so you'll need two ros::Time members one to store the previous time and one to store the current time, the duration is then simple one minus the other. This calculation cannot be done on the first iteration of the loop because there was no previous time so you'll need to detect and avoid this.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1